# Inserting week number in phpmyadmin database when submitting form based on current date

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, forms

I want to upload current week number in the database without showing it anywhere in the site when users submit a form. Although I do want to use the week number later to show "Winners of week XX" (main reason I want it uploaded to database). At this time I have created a form which does not refresh the page when submitted to the database. In phpmyadmin I have created a field called Week with type INT. If needed I can of course change this according to working code suggestions. I have spent the last 2 days searching the web and trying to make this work, but finally I decided to join the community and ask about it here. Any suggestions?

Do tell if anyone need me to specify some code. At this time I'm working with script in the index.html and PHP in a separate file.

Problem solved: $weekNumber = date("W"); worked like a charm.

Comment: Do you want to get number of week for current year?

Comment: I want to get the week number for when the form was submitted. So if a user submitted the form today, it would be week number 35. And if the user submitted the form next week, the submitted week number would be 36.

Comment: I identified the problem. A missing comma.......!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get week number by php function date as below and can insert it in DB as per your requirement.

```
$weekNumber = date("W");
```

Comment: Still won't work. Tried this approach in every way. Must be something I keep missing...

Comment: Are you getting any error? Add error_reporting(E_ALL) on the top of the page and check the error.

Comment: No, nothing (except for the CSS faults which are expected and not important).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your php:

```
$ddate = "2012-10-18";
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week = $date->format("W");
echo "Weeknummer: $week";
```

It will display-> Weeknummer: 42

Comment: Tried it earlier, didn't work. It actually stopped the whole form from submitting.